CsvHelper passing parameter into map constructor when registering class map
I am using CsvHelper to read a csv file and create a list of records from a file.
I have different types of csv files that contain data to be mapped to the same properties of my models but the headers and arrangements of the data in the file may be different.
I wanted to write a function that allows the user to map "his" type of csv files to the properties of the model.
In the constructor of the Map I am calling another method, to load the custom mapping that the user created
public Map(int accId)
{
    //Load selected model map
    CsvMap csvmap= new();
    csvmap.LoadMapForAccount(accId);
    //Mapping details
    Map(m => m.DateTime).Name(csvmap.DateTimeHeader);
}

The question is how can I pass the parameter int accId if I load the map like this:
csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<Map>();


RegisterClassMap has an overload that takes an instance of ClassMap rather than just a type. Create an instance with the accId to pass in.
csv.Context.RegisterClassMap(new Map(accId));


This is limited solution and will require exact header names in the file, no type conversion. How do you convert 20JAN2024 to Date, etc? And as OP pointed, files can be different, one header is a,b,c another x,y,z while the model could be only p1, p2, p3

Thanks a lot that was an easy solution! I was hovering over the method and it didnt show me that there is an overload for this method in the tooltip so I didnt bother checking...

@T.S. I am aware of that issue and I have an extra input option to select a date format ;) I only posted a tiny snippet of my code to precisely explain my question.
